# HTML CSS : How Can I Line Up Arrow, Checkbox & Headline In A Row?

Tags: html

How can I get the arrow, checkbox and headline text line up in a single row?

I need to have them line up as shown in this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPJji.jpg?

Thank you for taking your time to share your wisdom.

```css
#cbox {
  background-color: #FCF8E3;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-style: dashed;
}

.mainc {
  background-color: #FFFF99;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
}

#checkboxi {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#chead {
  color: #3bbb64;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!--Google Material Icon-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Checkbox_Unchecked by default -->
<div id="cbox">
  <div class="mainc">
    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px;color:red">forward</i>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxi" name="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox" id="ctext">
   <span id="chead">Headline Goes Here</span>   
  </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use flex display:

```
.flex{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items:center
}
```

```css
#cbox{
background-color: #FCF8E3;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.mainc{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
}
.flex{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items:center
}
#checkboxi{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
   transform: scale(1.5);
   /* margin-bottom: 15px;*/
}
#chead{
    color: #3bbb64;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!--Google Material Icon-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      
<!-- Checkbox_Unchecked by default -->
<div id="cbox">
 <div class="mainc">
   <div class="flex">
        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px;color:red">forward</i>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxi" name="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox" id="ctext">
   <span id="chead">Headline Goes Here</span>
   
  </label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You nailed it!! I just added margin left & right to the checkbox and it's all good now. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Flex, with simplified markup:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.material-icons {
  color: red
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <i class="material-icons">forward</i>
  <label for="c">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c">
    <span>1 year warranty</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm59fkn4/)

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't even know about flex. :)

Comment: There's probably a better solution with `grid` over `flex` as well

Comment: Thank you again. I don't know how to use grid, so I need to do some research about it.